# Proper Ukrainian keyboard layout for iPad

Tags: keyboard, ipad, magic-keyboard-ipad

I have an iPad Air (4th gen) with Magic Keyboard. However, I’m very displeased but the fact that the “Ukrainian” keyboard layout is non-standard in iOS, with two vowels (*и* and *і*) swapped. This is very annoying.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings > General > Keyboard > Hardware Keyboard and tap over at the right edge.  Make sure that you have "Ukrainian PC" checked (and not "automatic" or Ukrainian).

Comment: Ah, I see. I visited “Keyboards”, but not “Hardware Keyboard”. But now I also finally know how to disable the annoying auto-capitalization, auto-point and auto-correction. Thanks a lot!